# How to kill ostensibly immortal process?

Tags: nfs, rhel6, kill

I had some huge file transfers operating on an NFS mount. The server on which the mount point resided was carelessly rebooted, and now the server from which these large transfers were initiated seems to be bogged down by them.

If I run `top`, I see the following:

[image]

The first thing I tried was to run `kill` with each the -1 -2 -9 and -15 flags, and each of the process ids shown above in turn. This allowed me to proceed, but didn't kill the processes. The next thing I attempted was to reboot the server, but neither `reboot` nor `shutdown -r now` worked. When I ran `shutdown -r now` the standard broadcast message was sent out, but the sever did not reboot. I confirmed this by looking at the server uptime, which was 25 days.

So now I'm a little stuck. I'm running these commands as root.

EDIT: Here's another interesting tidbit:

[image]

In top, I don't see that any other processes are using more than a fraction of a percent of memory or more than 5% of CPU.

EDIT 2: output of `/var/log/messages`

[image]

Comment: If the parent process isn't 1, try killing that.

Comment: @Mlfe thanks! I just tried kill 1 per your advice but it didn't kill the init process.

Comment: I also unmounted the problem share, but that didn't allow me to kill the jobs

Comment: I siad dont kill 1 :). You could try a 'drastic' reboot. "sync; halt -f -d -n --reboot". This will forcibly reboot the host without switching runlevels. This might cause the host to become unresponsive and need physical interruption. Down to you to take that risk..

Comment: @Mlfe Thanks for the clarification! I'm a little frazzled, so I misunderstood it at first. If I don't get any additional answers within the next five minutes I'll give your "drastic" measure a try. The server is a PitA to physically access, so I'm trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @Mlfe I enacted the "drastic measure" and it didn't do *anything*. o_O What sort of gremlin has found his way into my server?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, time for something even more drastic!

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic
```

This instructs the kernel that when you kernel panic, to reboot the host in 1 second.

```
echo c >/proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This forces the kernel to panic. So hopefully you'll end up rebooting the host.

Comment: OK, that caused it to close the SSH connection. That's promising. Now for the long silence....   :)  Man I'm learning a lot today....

Comment: @Mlfe So it looks like some of my commands were getting through, and some weren't. I can't ping or SSH into the server, so it looks like I need to track down its physical location. Regardless, I bet those processes are finally killed, which is what I care about. Some people strive to be sysadmins, some have sysadmin duties thrust upon them :)

Comment: @DeeDee being thrown into the lion's den with a pocket full of meat is the best way to learn.

Comment: @Banjer Well, my name is "Daniel" XD

Comment: @Banjer Aaaaaand we're back. Many thanks, guys. You provided a wealth of information to which I'm sure I'll be returning in the future.

Comment: This is overwork. `echo b >| /proc/sysrq-trigger` is enough. It behaves almost like a hardware reset button.

Answer (score 1):

You've started the shutdown process, so your best bet is to get that thing rebooted.  If its a physical machine, then can you physically power off the server or via a service processor?

If not, and you think its these specific processes hanging up, then try and Kill all processes named `mv` and `gzip` with this:

`killall mv`

`killall gzip`

As a general disclaimer, **Be careful** with that killall command, as you don't want to accidentally kill some system process, so just be aware of what you're killing.

Also, see whats mounted with `df -h` and try umounting them.  I've seen my Linux systems hang on shutdown when they won't let go of an nfs mount.  I usually have to "lazy" unmount them with

`umount -l /path/of/mount/point`

**EDIT 1**

Other ways to gracefully reboot:

Does your system respond to `Ctrl+Alt+Del`?

If not, try the magic SysRQ key combo: `Alt+SysRq+R+E+I+S+U+B`.  Sysrq=PrintScreen button.  While holding down alt and sysrq keys, you type the REISUB key combo one after the other in order.  It basically kills off all processes first, does some other cleanup, and reboots.  This only works if magic sysrq is enabled in your kernel.  FYI:

```
R: Switch the keyboard from raw mode to XLATE mode
E: Send the SIGTERM signal to all processes except init
I: Send the SIGKILL signal to all processes except init
S: Sync all mounted filesystems
U: Remount all mounted filesystems in read-only mode
B: Immediately reboot the system, without unmounting partitions or syncing
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the killall commands, but the little buggers are still kicking. When I ran the lazy umount, it said that the path in question is already unmounted. Good to know that my initial umount worked though! Now I know how doctors must feel when they encounter MRSA :)

Comment: Anything else listed in `df -h`?  Any interesting logs in `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: df -h doesn't have anything particularly interesting. I edited the post in include the recent relevant content of /var/log/messages

Comment: see other reboot suggestions in my answer above.

Comment: that SysRQ commbo...how...i don't even have enough hands for that!

Comment: Thanks @Banjer! I'm on an SSH connection using Putty, so these solutions didn't work.

Comment: @acolyte haha, you actually only hold down Alt+SysRq with one hand, then run through the REISUB key combo one at-a-time with the other hand.   DeeDee: see Mlfe's answer regarding forcing kernel panic from command line.

Comment: @Banjer ohh.  i was going to say...